# mysql table createing new row instead of updating

Tags: php, mysql

Instead of finding that a row exists where 'bookName' equals 'bookName' and just updating, it creates a brand new row. What is wrong with my command?   thanks!

```
$query = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO custombookinfo (userId, sendToAddress, work, caseStudies, url, entryPoint, date, bookName) 
 VALUES ('$userId', '$emailAddress', '$work', '$caseStudies', '$url', '$entryPoint', '$date', '$bookName') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bookName = 'bookName'"
);
```

Comment: Does `bookName` have a UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) key? Is it collated correctly (language, case-sensitivity)?

Comment: bookName must be eithor primary key or unique key,"ON DUPLICATE KEY" can take effect!

Comment: I'll be that guy today and say please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: will look into using MySQLi. thanks peterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `INSERT` query is correct but I think you have failed to define `UNIQUE` constraint on column `bookName`. Execute the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE custombookinfo ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (bookName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to be UNIQUE in the table, you should create an index (PRIMARY or UNIQUE) for whether user_id, or bookName.

More details about **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html